# Uncaught TypeError: $player.jPlayer is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm helping a friend with [his site](http://anthonycasalena.ca/) and after updating his WordPress installation to address the recent security issue, the JPlayer plugin that was handling audio on his site stopped working.

Chrome's console shows the error in the title, but I don't know JS well enough to be able to debug it properly. I'm pretty sure that the plugin itself is loaded correctly, along with JQuery, in the page header. I checked it against the plugin's instructions and it all appears fine.

I've also updated the plugin itself to ensure that it's not some compatibility issue.

I did *not* build his site, nor am I familiar with this particular plugin at all, I'm just trying to see if it's an easy fix or if I have to restore a backup.

I assume it has something to do with how his web designer (they had a falling out) implemented it in the [main.js](https://gist.github.com/MariusMasalar/e7f8a39212b53482c933#file-main-js) file, but that's about as far as I've gotten.

Help?

Comment: I don't see an error in Chrome, just a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Really condensing and removing parts of main.js, it looks like

```
var $player = false,

$(document).ready(function() {
    if(!$player) {
        $("#jPlayer").jPlayer({
            ready: function() {
                $player = $(this); // IT'S BEING SET HERE !
                PlaylistPlay(playlistObject,trackIndex);
            }
        });
    } else {
        PlaylistPlay(playlistObject,trackIndex);
    }
});

function PlaylistPlay(lePID,trackIndex) {
    playTrack(trackIndex);  
}

function playTrack(index) { 
    $player.jPlayer("setMedia", {mp3: trackObject.mp3,oga: trackObject.oga}).jPlayer("play");
}
```

If you look closely at that, you'll see that there is a distinct possibility that `PlaylistPlay` can be called without `$player` being set to `$(this)`, it's actually almost a certaintity, which means that `$player` is `false`, and doing

```
false.jPlayer(...
```

doesn't really work, see the console output that confirms the variable is `false`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is not initializing correctly. On `$(document).ready()` it's trying to initialize the plugin and it's reporting a Flash error.

Here's the significant part of the code:

```
$("#jPlayer").jPlayer({
    ...
    error: function(event) {
        var out = "<p id=\"noSolution\">Sorry, you need an HTML5 capable browser or flash to be able to listen to music on this website.<br /> Reason: ";
        switch(event.jPlayer.error.type) {          
            case $.jPlayer.error.FLASH:
                out += "A problem with the Flash insertion on the page.";
            break;
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
});
```

Digging a bit deeper, I can trace this back to the `vimeo.jplayer` in the specific code block:

```
_flash_volume: function(a) {
    try {
        this._getMovie().fl_volume(a)
    } catch (b) {
        this._flashError(b)
    }
}
```

That function is throwing an exception because `this._getMovie()` does not have a property named `fl_volume`.

The error you actually see is a side-effect of this failure. You could try removing the line: `this._flashError(b)` from the above statement and see if the error can be safely ignored.

Comment: I've tried everything, in all browsers, and I can not for the life of me get a flash error, it only falls back to flash when HTML5 video isn't available. I've even tried emulating old IE, but then nothing works. If I go to that site, and click the play button at the top or any of the albums, I get an `undefined function` error, that's all? How did you get that error, in what browser etc ?

Comment: Win 7/Chrome 42. I suppose it may be related to the firewall at my work too... Also I just put a breakpoint in the `document.ready` and was able to get to it by stepping in through there.

Comment: I don't really don't know what the OP's problem is, there isn't much of a description of the error, so it could be anything, I was just wondering why I couldn't find the Flash error. Strangely enough the music actually starts playing when I disable Flash completely, because the `if` contidition then seems to go the other way, and `$player` is being set correctly, so the error I'm seeing could be related to Flash somehow as well ?

Comment: Thanks very much for the pointers, guys. Unfortunately I'm still no closer to figuring out what's going wrong here. If Flash is at the root of it, then is there a way to disable the Flash fallback entirely?

Comment: Actually that doesn't seem to work...just removed the Flash option entirely and it doesn't change anything. Still no audio and still the same console output.